# Android: FrameLayout squeezes View

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am using the following layout:

[image]

FrameLayout fills the entire Viewport, i.e. width and height are set to MATCH_PARENT

Width and height of RelativeLayout are set to WRAP_CONTENT

View1 to View5 have fixed dimensions e.g. width = 500, height = 50

View 5 lies near the border of FrameLayout and is squeezed by Android,
so that it lies fully within FrameLayout. The height of View5 should be 50 but unfortunately Android changes it to a smaller value.

How can I avoid, that Android changes the height of View5 ?

When I scroll RelativeLayout, the error is still existing.

A similar behavior is described here:
[button is squeezed when it exceeds layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760011/button-is-squeezed-when-it-exceeds-layout)

Comment: I don't know why do you use FrameLayout. RelativeLayout would be enough. Regarding your problem - try to use android:minHeight=50dp and android:maxHeight=50dp.

Comment: I am using both layouts because I want to scroll RelativeLayout within FrameLayout. FrameLayout can have only one child. Your proposal is unclear for me, a method setMaximumHeight() doesn't exist.

Comment: minHeight is xml parameter. You can use setMinimumHeight in code. maxHeight also exists but in eg. TextView so depending what kind of view do you use, it also can help(if available). Try only minHeight mabye it will help.

Comment: I have tested minHeight but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

A "*better*" Approach to this problem is to use a `ScrollView` like

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <View
             android:id="@+id/view1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
         <View
             android:id="@+id/view2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/view1" />
         <View
             android:id="@+id/view3"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="50dp"
             android:layout_below="@+id/view2" />
 <!-- YOU GET THE IDEA -->

    </RelativeLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```